# Extract the year and month from these strings and then replace the patterns found with others

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-group, regexp-replace

```py
import re, datetime
from calendar import monthrange

#examples:
input_text_substring = "los juegos se jugaran durante el transcurso del mes de octubre" #example 1
input_text_substring = "empiezan durante el transcurso del mes de febrero del año 2020" #example 2
input_text_substring = "empiezan durante el periodo del mes de septiembre" #example 3
input_text_substring = "empezaran durante el transcurso del mes de febrero del 2023" #example 4
input_text_substring = "creo que empezarian durante el transcurso del mes de diciembre 2021" #example 5
```

```py
es_month_dict = {"enero": "01", "febrero": "02", "marzo": "03", "abril": "04", "mayo": "05", "junio": "06", "julio": "07", "agosto": "08", "septiembre": "09", "octubre": "10", "noviembre": "11", "diciembre": "12"}

#Assumes that it is the current year if it is not explicitly indicated
if not re.search(r"(?:(?:del|de el)[\s|]*(?:año|ano)[\s|]*\d*|.*\d{4}$)", input_text_substring):
    input_text_substring += " de " + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y') + " "

#do substring identification capture groups...
identified_year = #extract year
identified_month = #extract month
last_day_in_this_month = (monthrange(int(identified_year), int(identified_month)))[1]

time_period_in_this_month = "[01 -- " + str(last_day_in_this_month) + "] de " + str(identified_month)

months = r"enero|febrero|marzo|abril|mayo|junio|julio|agosto|septiembre|octubre|noviembre|diciembre"
pattern_to_replace = r"(?:(?:en|durante)[\s|]*(?:el|los)[\s|]*(?:transcurso|trancurso|periodo|dias)[\s|]*(?:del|de)[\s|]*(?:mes[\s|]*de|mes)[\s|]*(?:" + months + r")|durante[\s|]*(?:el[\s|]*mes[\s|]*de|el[\s|]*mes|)[\s|]*(?:" + months + r"))"

#do the replacement...
input_text_substring = re.sub(pattern_to_replace, time_period_in_this_month, input_text_substring)


print(repr(input_text_substring)) #output
```

The **correct outputs** that this will need to get in each of the examples:

```py
input_text_substring = "los juegos se jugaran [01 -- 31] 10 2022" #example 1
input_text_substring = "empiezan [01 -- 29] 02 2020" #example 2
input_text_substring = "empiezan [01 -- 30] 09 2022" #example 3
input_text_substring = "empezaran [01 -- 28] 02 2023" #example 4
input_text_substring = "creo que empezarian [01 -- 31] 12 2021" #example 5
```

How should I extract the month and year, to be able to pass it to the `(monthrange(int(identified_year), int(identified_month))` method and have it return the number of days of that month in that year, and then replace it in the original string and obtain these outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the month, you can simply search for the dictionary term in the string, then to find the year, you can use regex to extract the year from your string.

Example:

```
for key, value in s_month_dict.items():
    if key in input_text_substring:
        identified_month = value
        break
wordList = re.findall(r'\b\S*%s\S*\b' % re.escape('20'), input_text_substring)
for word in wordList:
    if len(word) == 4:
        identified_year = word
        break
print identified_month, ' ', identified_year
```

The preceding code produces the following outputs:

```
10   2022
02   2020
09   2022
02   2023
12   2021
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, in the case of the `example 3`, I got confused and put `11` when for September month (`septiembre` in spanish) the correct output is `09` (following the order of the months of the year), .now i have edited it. a single detail, it is possible that it covers years that are not exactly 4 figures, if and only if before the number of the year it says `"del año"` and then the number?

Comment: For example, for those years that are indicated and that do not have 4 numerical figures, then what should I do or if this pattern `(?:del|de el)[\s|]*(?:año|ano)[\s|]*\d*` , How could I add that to this line `wordList = re.findall(r'\b\S*%s\S*\b' % re.escape('20'), input_text_substring)` of your code?

Comment: I took advantage of the fact that your code assumes the current year if not indicated, and appends it to the string, so by placing my code in the position indicated by ```#do substring identification capture groups...```, the current year is the result when the year is missing from the original string. Are you saying that there are additional unaccounted for scenarios?

Comment: I was ask if it was possible to consider years that were not necessarily 4 digits, even so I have achieved it with this line  `re.findall(r"(?:del|de el)[\s|](?:año|ano)[\s|]\d*", input_text_substring)` that I was able to put together thanks to taking your code as a reference. Really thanks for the help ;)